# How to change Resolution of a Rejected Jira without reopening it?

Tags: jira

I forgot to set the correct Resolution when I rejected my issue. Is there a possibility to change it to some other option, like Won't fix?
I wouldn't really like to repoen it and I am not an administrator.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at JIRA's REST API system, you could change the resolution that way : https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Update-resolution-field-with-JIRA-REST-API-to-quot-Done-quot-in/qaq-p/528782

Comment: Thanks, however it was easier to reopen it...

Comment: You can use ScriptRunner for JIRA plugin, they contain built-in script for bulk change resolution via provided JQL filter